# Represent data as a table with diagonally split color-coded cells

Tags: visualization, table

I have two rows of values that I'd like to represent as a table, where cells are diagonally divided showing color-coded values with column A and column B values for each row  such as below:

[image]

Any neat idea how produce such design? The hardest part for me is dividing the cells diagonally.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with a generic utility:

```
SplitBox[{upColor_, downColor_}, {upValue_, downValue_}] :=
Graphics[
  {{upColor, Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}, 
   {downColor, Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}]}, 
   Text[upValue, {.3, .7}], 
   Text[downValue, {.7, .3}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 100]
```

Demo:

```
GraphicsGrid[
  Apply[
    SplitBox, 
    Table[{{RandomColor[], RandomColor[]}, {RandomReal[500], RandomReal[100]}}, {4}, {3}], 
    {2}]]
```

[image]

Now you'll need to add any styling and presentation details you want.

Presumably the colors are determined by the values, so you'll need some helper functions that return a color for a given argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[labeledSplitRectangle]

labeledSplitRectangle[{topcolor_, bottomcolor_}, 
    {toplabel_, bottomlabel_}, dir_ : 1] := 
 Module[{c = Transpose @ CoordinateBounds[Rectangle @ ##], 
    w = {{3/4, 1/4}, (dir /. {-1 -> Reverse, 1 -> Identity}) @ {1/3, 2/3}}}, 
  {{LinearGradientFilling[ 
      {0, 1/2, 1/2, 1} -> {topcolor, topcolor, bottomcolor, bottomcolor}, 
      dir ArcTan @@ N @ Cross[Subtract @@ c], "Fixed"], Rectangle @@ c}, 
    Text[toplabel, Dot @@@ Thread[{w, Transpose @ c}]], 
    Text[bottomlabel,  Dot @@@ Thread[{1 - w, Transpose @ c}]]}] &
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[7];

Graphics[{labeledSplitRectangle[{Red, Cyan}, 
   Style[#, FontSize -> Scaled[.03]] & /@ 
     {"top label", "bottom label"}][{1, 1}, {3, 2}], 
 labeledSplitRectangle[{RandomColor[], RandomColor[]}, 
   Style[#, FontSize -> Scaled[.03]] & /@ 
     {"lbl 1", "lbl 2"}][{2, 0}, {3, 1}], 
 labeledSplitRectangle[{RandomColor[], RandomColor[]}, 
   Style[#, FontSize -> Scaled[.03]] & /@ 
     {"A", "B"}, -1][{3.5, .5}, {5, 3}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1];

tbl = Round[RandomReal[1, {7, 4, 2}], .01];

Graphics[
 {MapIndexed[
  labeledSplitRectangle[
     Hue /@ #, 
     Style[#, 16, ColorNegate @ Hue @ #] & /@ #] @ #2 &, 
   tbl, {2}]}, 
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[7], Range[4]}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], White], 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 1 -> 100]
```

[image]

Replace `labeledSplitRectangle[...]` with `labeledSplitRectangle[..., -1]` to get

[image]

```
Graphics[{MapIndexed[
   labeledSplitRectangle[
      {ColorData["DeepSeaColors"] @ First @ #, 
       ColorData["SolarColors"] @ Last @ #}, 
      Style[#, 16, If[# < .5, White, Black]] & /@ #] @ #2 &, tbl, {2}]},
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[7], Range[4]}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], White], 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 1 -> 100]
```

[image]